# Можно ли в Python отследить использование класса из модуля?

Tags: python

Возможен ли способ выяснить - был ли проимпортирован класс\атрибут\функция из текущего файла в другом файле текущего проекта?
Например, есть код:

```
file01.py
    class Foo1():
        pass

    class Foo2():
        pass


file02.py
    import file01
    class Bar1():
        f1 = file01.Foo1()
        f2 = file01.Foo2()

    class Bar2():
        pass
```

Для задачи есть функция:

```
def inspection(module):
    for i in dir(module):
        <magic>
        print('class {0} used in {1}'.format(class_name, module_name))
```

Что при выполнении:
`inspection(file01)`
Выдаст результат типа:

```
class Foo1 used in: file02
class Foo2 used in: None
```

Подобный функционал был бы полезен для написания `docstring` для файлов `__init__.py`. В котором, согласно [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), необходимо отобразить экспортироемую пакетом информацию.

Comment: А в каком ключе Вам это надо знать? На этапе выполнения? На этапе написания кода? Именно проимпортирован или ещё и использован?

Comment: Есть проект в котором несколько сотен файлов. Проект не документирован абсолютно никак. В связи с этим подобный функционал поможет лучше понять структуру проекта. Эдакий реверс-инжениринг. Сейчас копаю в сторону модуля inspect из стандартной библиотеки, но сомневаюсь, что поможет.

Comment: Так а чем Вам мешает воспользоватся что нибудь типа PyCharm или любой другой IDE для анализа кода? Либо же какими-нибудь анализаторами кода типа pylint например?

Comment: `{class}.__module__` ?

Comment: Надеюсь дополнение вопроса поможет понять меня лучше

Comment: Можно (к примеру, используя `__getattr__`/metaclass/`inspect.currentframe()`/2to3/разные статические анализаторы). Статически может только часть информации доступна, но может быть достаточно на практике.

Если только внутреннее использование интересует, то можно проанализировать импорты и соответствующие обращения к атрибутам в каждом модуле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожелению без запуска кода никак

```
import sys


def watch_uses(cls, log):
    class MetaTemp(type(cls)):
        def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            call_frame = sys._getframe(1)
            log.append('{}:{}'.format(
                call_frame.f_locals['__file__'], call_frame.f_lineno
            ))
            return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

    class new_cls(cls, metaclass=MetaTemp):
        pass

    return new_cls


class C:
    pass


uses_C = []
C = watch_uses(C, uses_C)

#здесь вам нужно как-то происпользовать C
c = C()
c = C()

print(uses_C) #может вывести: ['./t.py:27', './t.py:28']
```

Comment: В том и "фишка", что при импорте код исполняется (об этом можно узнать у Лутца в книге "Изучаем Python" в разделе "Импортирование и перезагрузка модулей"). Возможно в разделе <magic> функции из вопроса необходимо проимпортировать все модули всего проекта, чтобы выполнить сопоставление классов из модулей и текущих классов

Comment: Вы не очень понимаете что значит выполняеться в контексте "компиляции"

Comment: Для примера 2 кода в модуле: `C()` выполнит вызов С и вы его увидете. А код `lambda: C()` уже ничего не выполнит и его использования вы не увидете.